# Google Colab Annotate

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

The bounding box coordinates of the `colab_utils.annotate` is:

`np.array([[0.41941667, 0.08333333, 0.89941667, 0.7296875]], dtype=np.float32),`

This is the bounding box coordinates of apps like labelImg:

```
<bndbox>
            <xmin>948</xmin>
            <ymin>537</ymin>
            <xmax>1416</xmax>
            <ymax>650</ymax>
</bndbox>
```

**Question:**
is the coordinates of google colab normalised according to the pixels of the image?
like this:?

```
# Bounding box coordinates
xmin = 948
ymin = 537
xmax = 1416
ymax = 650

# Image dimensions
width = 1920
height = 1080

# Compute normalized coordinates
xmin_norm = xmin / width
ymin_norm = ymin / height
xmax_norm = xmax / width
ymax_norm = ymax / height
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever find an answer to this question? 
I can't use "colab_utils.annotate" but I'm trying to converge to its results but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/19ce8ecda0732e52d943ccdf540a5659d103c2fc/research/object_detection/utils/colab_utils.py#L324-L331)

```py
                function drawRect(o){
                    // draw a predefined rectangle
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.beginPath(o);
                    ctx.rect(o.x * image.width, o.y * image.height, o.w * image.width, o.h * image.height);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
```

The format seems to be **relative xyxy**, just as proposed by @Carolyn.